# Auto Upload Files When Added to a Folder

Tags: jquery, upload, directory

I was wondering how i could get file to automatically upload when added to a folder on my computer.

Simliar to what dropdox does so that when i add a new file to a folder on my desktop it will automatically recognize this an start and upload in the background and and place it on a server??

I have been googling could some point me in the right direction on how to learn this and what technology is used i.e ajax php jquery.

I understand this is probably quite a broad question but want to find the right places to start:)

Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINUX server's Cronjobs. Cronjobs is scheduled tasks. You have code a script which checks this folder and if there is a new file, uploads it. And you have to run this script every (for example) 5 minutes , via cronjobs.

But your computer must be open, always. And i'm not sure, can you list your local folders. Maybe you can use some technologies for this.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replay, I havent managed to find a solutionat the moment where the cron can be used on local folders your right, at the moment i am looking at maybe adobe flex to create a desktop application that could preform this task. Im going to do some googling now to see if their might be a way to do it on a local folder.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Adobe Flex , maybe you can create a widget with Flex.